# installation of openssl on centos 6.3

Tags: openssl, centos

```
# cd openssl-0.9.8o
# ./config shared –prefix=/usr/local
# make
# make test
```

when i tried install and run make test .. received below error.

```
if [ -n "" ]; then \
          ../util/shlib_wrap.sh ./fips_randtest; \
        fi
starting big number library test, could take a while...
test BN_add
Add test failed!
make[1]: *** [test_bn] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/openssl-0.9.8o/test'
make: *** [tests] Error 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Is it necessarily to compile Openssl from source code? if not try to use:

```
# yum -y install openssl
```

from command line, it's straight forward to install using [YUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified),
it's use the internet to download and install the needed RPM packages.

In case you don't have internet access from your CentOS 6.3 machine, download the Openssl package from [here](ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/linux/scientificlinux/6.3/x86_64/updates/fastbugs/openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.i686.rpm), copy it to your machine then install it using this command:

```
# rpm -Uvh openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.i686.rpm
```

Comment: Some people prefer to build it since Red Hat deratives strips EC Support from openssl... Some people need that EC support.

Comment: yum update and yum install still point to the obsolete version 1.0.1 on centOS, don't ask me why but it does.